# How to use android.os.Build class from a Java Project in intellij?

Tags: java, class

I need to use android.os.Build class for checking android device info, how can I implement this class in my code ?

The class is going to get OS information(it can be windows, linux or android).
My class will not be in the android project.
Currently I can't get Android OS information because I don't know how to implement android.os.Build...

here is my class:

```
public class SystemInformationCollector {

public String getOSInfo(){
    if (isAndroid()){
        return  getAndroidOSInfo();
    }
    else{
        return getDeviceOSInfo();
    }
}

private String getAndroidOSInfo() {
    return "Kernel Version: " + getOSVerion() + "(" + getAndroidBuildVersion() + ") OS API Level: " + getAndroidAPI();
}
private String getDeviceOSInfo(){
    return "OS: " + getOSName()+ " OS Version: " + getOSVerion() + " OS Architecture: " + getOSArch();
}

private boolean isAndroid() {
    try{
        Class.forName("android.app.Activity");
        return true;
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

//only works for desktop
private String getOSName(){
    return System.getProperty("os.name");
}
//works for Android(shows kernel version) and Desktop(shows os version) devices
private String getOSVerion(){
    return System.getProperty("os.version");
}
//only works for desktop
private String getOSArch(){
    return System.getProperty("os.arch");
}

//works for Android
private String getAndroidBuildVersion(){
    return Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL;
}
//works for Android
private int getAndroidAPI(){
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
}
}
```